# DynamoDB global tables using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to create DynamoDB global tables using the CloudFormation template? I was looking at this AWS doc - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables.tutorial.html#creategt_cli

and it seems like one can create DynamoDB global tables only with the Console or the AWS CLI and not through CloudFormation templates?

Or Is there a specific hack where I'll create all the replica tables using CloudFormation and I'll create the global table manually using the AWS CLI?

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/57

Comment: Oh that's cool! Thanks for the link @PatMyron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable'" to create global table in CFN. A good resource is https://www.capitalone.com/tech/cloud/dynamodb-global-tables-with-cloudformation/.

This feature was released on May 17, 2021, https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/amazon-dynamodb-global-tables-now-support-aws-cloudformation/.

Answer (score 5):

The `DynamoDB Global Table` was introduced during the late 2017. Yes, as you mentioned, you can create the global tables using the AWS console or AWS CLI.

However, creating the global table using cloudformation template is yet to be available.

Meanwhile, please use the console or AWS CLI to create dynamodb global table.

Comment: Being now on the fence about continuing with ClodFormation or switch to Terraform the need to have global table makes me going Terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_global_table.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it through cloudformation, you can do so using custom resources. It is pretty straight forward and easy to use. You can use their createGlobalTable API in your custom resource.

Comment: Could not find any working example. Any direction will be helpful.

Comment: Looks like it's doable via [lambda-based-custom-resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) just not sure if it's worth the headache

Comment: I did try and experiment with it, don't have anything quite to share though. The difficulty I faced was to get the tables created in all regions and then verifying that the global table is created only when all the regional tables are all created and ready to go and handling edge cases.

Comment: The createGlobalTable and friends are only for the old version of global dynamodb tables.  I'm working on a solution that uses the new version, but I'm still working through all of the nuances. I would think that AWS should have an example of a global dynamodb table.  We want to use it as a multi-region failover and coordinate the changes via streams events to lambdas.

Comment: I second @Brandon, all `*_global_table_*` APIs in boto3 are only for 2017 version of global tables. For 2019 version use create_table, describe_table and update_table instead. Some one can take 'lambda-based-custom-resource' from paul-liang 's above comment and modify it to use create_table/describe_table & update_table instead of `*_global_table_*` APIs.

Comment: BTW, I finished it: https://github.com/blmille1/cloudformation-templates/blob/master/multi-region-failover/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Your hack gets to the bottom of it. Create everything (including streams settings) with cloudformation. Then one manually enabled global tables on each created table. If you want the IOPS to be the same across all regions then your cloudformation will likely handle all the changes you need in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet implemented but it is present in the AWS roadmap

```
GlobalTable:
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable
Properties:
GlobalTableName: !Ref Table
ReplicationRegions:
 - us-east-1
 - us-west-2
```

Ref

- https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/57
- https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/380

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cloudformation now supports DynamoDB Global Tables. Or, at least it's written up in the docs, but I'm not sure if this solves your problem:
[AWS Cloudformation DynamoDB Global table documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-globaltable.html)

From the docs:

> The AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable resource enables you to create and manage a Version 2019.11.21 global table. This resource cannot be used to create or manage a Version 2017.11.29 global table.

Comment: Yes it does! Finally!